# js file is not loading in chrome (incognito window)

Tags: .htaccess

i am trying to load a javascript file from another domain through the htaccess file in the below format.
Header set Content-Security-Policy: "default-src: 'self'; script-src: 'unsafe-inline', 'unsafe-eval', 'self' *.example.com https://example.com http://example.com;"

I have verified in google chrome the js file is loading, but when i verified in incognito mode the where the js file is not loading (https://example.com)

kindly help me how to load the js file in incognito window.

note : After clearing the browser cache also its not working

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show screenshots please

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Give a _proper_ explanation of what you are embedding where, and quote the _exact_ error messages you are getting. Please go read [ask] first of all, and then edit your question.